# laravel vuejs authentication jwt

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt

I have one project that building with laravel ans vue js.
authentication is jwt.
login api is working and show me status success.
this is my login code:

```
  public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('phone_number', 'password');
        if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = $this->guard()->user();
            if ($user['block'] == 0 && $user['active'] == 1) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200)->header('Authorization', $token);
            }

        }
        return response()->json(['error' => 'login_error'], 401);
    }
```

but user appi and refresh api do not working.
after login in inspect i see undefined

```
public function user(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $show['id'] = $user['id'];
        $show['name'] = $user['name'];
        $show['family'] = $user['family'];
        $show['role_id'] = $user['role_id'];
        $show['username'] = $user['username'];
        $show['image'] = $user['profile_image'];
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'data' => $show,
        ]);
    }
```

and this is refresh api:

```
public function refresh()
{
    if ($token = $this->guard()->refresh()) {
        return response()
            ->json(['status' => 'successs'], 200)
            ->header('Authorization', $token);
    }
    return response()->json(['error' => 'refresh_token_error'], 401);
}
```

in my editor this code undefined:

```
->refresh()
```

Comment: try to get your refresh token from this method `auth()->refresh()`

Comment: Did you check token expiration? The refresh() method regenerate a token if the current token is expired. So it needs before using user method.